# transform pandas dataframe column via Interpolation

Tags: pandas, scipy, interpolation, python-3.6

i am looking to apply a 1d interpolation on a df and am not sure how to this in an efficient way. Here goes:

```
In [8]: param
Out[8]: 
             alpha  beta       rho        nu
0.021918  0.544953   0.5 -0.641566  6.549623
0.041096  0.449702   0.5 -0.062046  5.047923
0.060274  0.428459   0.5 -0.045312  3.625387
0.079452  0.424686   0.5 -0.049508  2.790139
0.156164  0.423139   0.5 -0.071106  1.846614
0.232877  0.414887   0.5 -0.040070  1.334070
0.328767  0.415757   0.5 -0.042071  1.109897
```

I would like the new index (but dont mind to reset_index() if needed) to look like this:

```
np.array([0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25])
```

So the corresponding values for alpha, beta, rho, nu need to be interpolated.
Came up with the following which only works for one column and only if x and y have the same dimensions:

```
x = np.array([0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25])
y = np.array(param.alpha)
f = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic', fill_value='extrapolate')
f(x)
```

Appreciate any pointer towards an efficient solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `reindex` and `interpolate` then index selection with `loc`:

```
param.reindex(new_idx.tolist()+param.index.values.tolist())\
     .sort_index()\
     .interpolate(method='cubic')\
     .bfill()\
     .loc[new_idx]
```

Output:

```
         alpha  beta       rho        nu
0.02  0.544953   0.5 -0.641566  6.549623
0.04  0.452518   0.5 -0.073585  5.138333
0.06  0.428552   0.5 -0.044739  3.641854
0.08  0.424630   0.5 -0.049244  2.772958
0.10  0.423439   0.5 -0.047119  2.294109
0.15  0.423326   0.5 -0.069473  1.873499
0.20  0.419130   0.5 -0.060861  1.573724
0.25  0.412985   0.5 -0.029573  1.221732
```

Comment: one more question. How do i best avoid having duplicates?

Comment: `param[~param.index.duplicated()]` does the trick but is there a better way?